# How does the implicitly created Form work?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

If I make a new Windows Forms project and add a second Form (Form2), I can show the implicitly created form simply by referring to the class name:

```
Form2.Show()
```

If I look up the definition of [Form.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx) procedure, it is not listed as a Shared member of the Form class. How is it that I am able to call Show() on the Form2 class name?

Comment: are you sure you don't have an instance?

Comment: @DanielA.White If I hover over the name where I call it, it says "Class Form2", if I however a name of an instance i created with New(), it says "Dim AForm As WindowsApplication1.Form2". So, it's not an instance unless the IDE is not accurate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When are default form instances created on application startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906660/when-are-default-form-instances-created-on-application-startup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it, and then decompiled the executable with ILSpy.

It seems to be silently rewriting `Form2.Show()` into `MyProject.Forms.Form2.Show()` instead.

`MyProject.Forms` is a generated class that encapsulates a lazy-instantiated singleton instance of each form in the project.

This appears to be a feature of the IDE rather than the compiler, because in LINQPad, I get "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

Comment: There must be more to it that just a lazily-initialised singleton instance. I'd expect it to also be thread-static leading to all kinds of problems when people try things like `Form1.Invoke(...)` from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Yes, there is more to it, that was the 30 second glance summary. Looks like you're correct about thread-static anyway. Also see related question for some more discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/why-is-there-is-a-default-instance-of-every-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c