# The Dialog Form remembers last button focus. How to reset it?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a custom form which is open as Form.ShowDialog()

This form acts as a confirmation form. It asks a question whether you want to accept or decline the previously entered input in ComboBox & TextBox.

If you click OK, the input is saved into Excel File.

If you click Cancel, the input is not saved.

The problem I am having is that:

When you click cancel. The form.ShowDialog() is closed. (Which is fine.)

But when the form.ShowDialog() is open again. It retains the focus on the Cancel Button. So if you try to confirm the entry with "Enter" key, you cancel it instead.

My question is. Why does the Form.ShowDialog() retain the focus on the buttons after closing?

The Form.ShowDialog() has accept button "OK" [tabindex = 1], and cancel button "Cancel" [tabindex = 2] which are set to <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

(To note again)The focus of the buttons remains after closing the form.

The portion of the code using the Dialog:

```
    ElseIf ComboBoxBP.SelectedItem = ComboBoxBP.SelectedItem And TextBoxBP.Text = TextBoxBP.Text Then

        form.Label1.Text = ComboBoxBP.SelectedItem
        form.Label2.Text = TextBoxBP.Text
        form.ShowDialog()

        If form.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

            SiE()

        ElseIf form.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then

            LabelBPBot.Text = "Canceled."

        End If

    End If
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know why, but without seeing your code I cant be certain, so...

Comment: I actually avoided posting the code because it's kind off... Messy. I'd need to post the code from 1 form, then another, and finally the dialogform. So That's why I tried to put in in words.

Comment: the problem is in your *code* not your *words*.  Just need how you are using/showing the Form

Comment: I updated my post with the code.

Comment: the last bit, right?  You really have a form named `form`?  Thats a type name

Comment: The letters were on different language, so I changed the name of the form. Yeah, the last bit. :)

Comment: this might help with the question you were trying to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24906660/1070452

Comment: Thanks! I've bookmarked it, and will read it tomorrow, when my heads clears a bit ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `.ShowDialog()` closing the form does not dispose of it as with a normal form.  This is because once a Dialog "closes" it actually just hides so we can get info from it before it actually goes away.

The second issue is that forms are classes (it says so at the top of every one of them:)

```
Public Class Form1
    ...
```

So, *instances* of them should be created.  VB allows `Form1.Show` or `Form1.ShowDialog()` to use a "default instance" and it is a shame that it does.

Combine these 2 tidbits and what you have is a case where the form you showed last time is still around *in the same state* as when you last used it, including the last focused control.  You are only using a "fresh copy" of the form the first time, after that, you are just reusing the old instance.  Remedy:

```
Using Dlg As New Form1             ' form1 is the class, dlg is the instance
   ... do stuff

   Dim res As DialogResult = Dlg.ShowDialog()

   If res = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
       '... do stuff
   End If

End Using                          ' dispose of Dlg
```

Eventually, you will run into similar issues using the default instance of the other forms (`LForm.Show`).  Just Say No to Default Form instances.

Comment: I'll try this, and will get back at you.

Comment: Thanks for the neat explanation, and how to fix it.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow... your solution finally help me... can be same done with : `Dim res As DialogResult = Form1.ShowDialog() : '*if dialogOK do stuff*' : Form1.Dispose()` or it's better way to use `Using/End Using` block? thx.