# How to stop a DataGridView removing columns on subsequent form loads?

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview

I have a child form that is launched by a user `Button` click. The form has a `DataGridView` on it. The `DataGridview` is bound to a `List(Of T)` in the form's `OnLoad` event which then also removes some columns, sets up column headings, alignment and width.

This works fine the first time the form is launched. However the second time the form is launched an an exception is raised for "Index was out of range". This seems to be related to any attempt to index the DataGridView using the `.Columns` property.

Seems like the DataGridView remembers the previous settings, that the columns were previously removed and so this second removal of columns uses indexes that are out of range...

As a test I reduced the set-up of the view to setting the DataSource and removing the first column. The first time  the form is loaded the first column is removed; the next time the next column is removed also; the next time the next column is removed, and so on.

How can I either have the form just remove "Absolute index" columns or just remove them the once, or even have the columns and DataSource and so forth all cleared on form exit so that the next time the form opens it all starts from scratch?

Comment: It will only remember the old settings if you didnt dispose of the form or perhaps if you are using the default form instance.

Comment: My Form closes use `Me.Close()` and it is a regular form, launched from the default main form using `Sub LaunchformClick()Handles.LaunchForm.Click Dim Myform As New MyformType MyForm.ShowDialog(Me) End sub`

Comment: @Plutonix Just added `MyForm.Dispose()` below `Myform.ShowDialog(Me)` and that solved it. So if you would like to make your comment an answer I'll mark it as such

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187484/1070452  AndAlso http://stackoverflow.com/q/29658054/1070452

Comment: Will mark as duplicate so